# how can i get data from adapter and show in Activity in Android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-adapter

In my application I want show countries in **`dialog`**. In my application has some `editTexts` in `mainActivity`, when click on **Contry** `editText` show countryDialog and sort countries in this dialog (I get this countries from server).

I want when click on county name, set this country on `editText`.

**my adapter codes:**

```
public class CountryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    private List<CountryDatum> mData;
    private Context context;

    public CountryAdapter(List<CountryDatum> mData, Context context) {
        this.mData = mData;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh;
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_country, parent, false);
        vh = new DataViewHolder(v);

        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        if (holder instanceof DataViewHolder) {
            ((DataViewHolder) holder).countryListTxt.setText(mData.get(position).getName() + "");
            ((DataViewHolder) holder).countryListTxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "" + mData.get(position).getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public void add(List<CountryDatum> models) {
        mData.addAll(models);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void clear() {
        mData.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class DataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView countryListTxt;

        public DataViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            countryListTxt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.countryNameTxt);
        }
    }

}
```

**Main Activity codes:**

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    private String countryName = "";

    @BindView(R.id.registerCountryEdtTxt)
    EditText countryListEdt;
    @BindView(R.id.registerDateBirthEdtTxt)
    EditText birthDayEdt;
    private CountryAdapter mAdapter;
    private List<CountryDatum> models = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context context;
    private Dialog dialog;
    private RecyclerView countryRecyler;
    private ProgressBar countryProgress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        //Initialize
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        context = RegisterActivity.this;
        mAdapter = new CountryAdapter(models, context);

    }

    @OnClick({R.id.registerCountryEdtTxt, R.id.registerCountryInptLay})
    void selectCountry() {
        getData();
    }

    @OnClick({R.id.registerDateBirthInptLay, R.id.registerDateBirthEdtTxt})
    void selectBirthDay() {
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
                RegisterActivity.this,
                now.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                now.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        );
        datePickerDialog.setVersion(DatePickerDialog.Version.VERSION_1);
        datePickerDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "Datepickerdialog");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        String date = "You picked the following date: " + dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year;
        birthDayEdt.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);
    }

    public void getData() {
        dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_country);
        countryRecyler = (RecyclerView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.countryRecyclerView);
        countryProgress = (ProgressBar) dialog.findViewById(R.id.countryDialog_progress);
        countryRecyler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
        countryRecyler.setHasFixedSize(true);
        countryProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        InterfaceApi api = ApiClient.getClient().create(InterfaceApi.class);
        Call<CountryResponse> call = api.getCountryList();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<CountryResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<CountryResponse> call, Response<CountryResponse> response) {
                try {
                    if (response.body() != null) {
                        models.clear();
                        models.addAll(response.body().getData());
                        countryProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        countryRecyler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<CountryResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

How can I when click on country names (**from adapter**), set this name for `registerCountryEdtTxt.setText` (**in mainActivity**)? how can I it?

I am amateur, please help me <3

Comment: now adapter click you got toast comes with correct data  ?

Comment: @MageshPandian, yes my friend. I want show this data into editText

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In adapter create on interface to transfer data

```
public class CountryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
  public interface onListClickedRowListner {
    void onListSelected(int mposition);
 }
}
```

> and in adapter constructor

```
onListClickedRowListner listner;
public CountryAdapter(List<CountryDatum> mData, Context context,onListClickedRowListner listner) {
    this.mData = mData;
    this.context = context;
    this.listner = listner;

}
```

> and in onBindViewHolder

```
    @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            if (holder instanceof DataViewHolder) {
                ((DataViewHolder) holder).countryListTxt.setText(mData.get(position).getName() + "");
                ((DataViewHolder) holder).countryListTxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "" + mData.get(position).getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        listner.onListSelected(position);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

> and implements this listner in mainActivity
>   and onListSelected in this method you get position using that position get value from mData and assign to any view in your activity.

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
            CountryAdapter.onListClickedRowListner {
    .
    .
    .

       @Override
        public void onListSelected (int listposition){
         Log.d("Tag",""+listposition);
       }
}
```

> and in you oncreate change like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    //Initialize
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    context = RegisterActivity.this;
    mAdapter = new CountryAdapter(models, context,this);

}
```

Comment: Thanks my friend, and now how can I use this in mainActivity? can you send me full code? please, please

Comment: @AngelM like this implement in your activity, you get the position which you clicked in that list and using that position and with your data get your value and shown in any view in that acitivity

Comment: how you passing data to CountryAdapter can you tell that , i mean the data source??

Comment: mData.get(position) will return object and get value from that.

Comment: please see my update post. I get data from server with retrofit2. and fill this data in mainActivity and when click click on editText show dialog. please see my update post and help me. I really need this help

Comment: onListSelected in this method you get correct position?

Comment: when add this listener on adapter, show me adapter in main activity and I should add listener to adapter constructor in mainActivity.

Comment: Thanks, but I have other issue! I use your code but when click on items in Toast show me position : 2, but in log show me position : 1 . not show true item positions! how can fix it?

Comment: you toasting Id and in that method position will come cross check that both  have same value. i hope so it wont.

Comment: Ok my friend I fix it. but I have question, for example I have send name, id, code from adapter and set into mainActivity for editTexts. how each name, id, code I write one interface? please help me for this question

Comment: onListSelected in this method i send position, instead of position, use number of parameters you want to get it in main acitivity.
 listner.onListSelected(mData.get(position).getId(),mData.get(position).name()) like this

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution . In your activity class do this.

```
countryRecyler.setAdapter(mAdapter,registerCountryEdtTxt);
```

then in adapter class

```
   private List<CountryDatum> mData;
    private Context context;
    private EditText mEditText;
     public CountryAdapter(List<CountryDatum> mData, Context 
                  context,EditText edittext) {
        this.mData = mData;
        this.context = context;
        mEditText=edittext;
    }

@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        if (holder instanceof DataViewHolder) {
            ((DataViewHolder) holder).countryListTxt.setText(mData.get(position).getName() + "");
            ((DataViewHolder) holder).countryListTxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "" + mData.get(position).getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  mEditText.setText(mData.get(position).getName())
                }
            });
        }
}
```